# A question on consecutive prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prime numbers:
$2$ $3$ $5$ $7$ $11$ $13$ $17$ $19$ $23$ $29$ ....

Difference between to consecutive primes:
$1$ $2$ $2$ $4$ $2$ $4$ $2$ $4$ $6$ ....

We know that there are infinite prime numbers. This is Ok. But does the difference between two consecutive prime numbers have any upper bound as the primes go to infinity? Can it be infinite?

Comment: There are arbitrarily long sequences of successive integers, all of which are composite. (Start with $n!+2$.)

Comment: If some sequence converges to infinity, then it is not said to converge, as far as I know.

Comment: @DavidMitra A very reasonable point raised.

Comment: Or $\{(n+1)!+i\}_{i=2}^{i=n+1}$ shows that $\lim\sup\{p_{n+1}-p_{n}\}=\infty$.

Comment: I guess $n!+2$ is an example. If so you are comparing a sequence with a known formula to a sequence which does not have a known formula. I didn't get it.

Comment: On the other hand, as far as I know (which isn't much), I think it's unknown if there is an $N$ such that  the differences are at most   $N$ infinitely often.  Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can shed some light here. (A famous conjecture states that $N=2$ might work.)

Comment: @DavidMitra: It is known that there are infinitely many prime gaps less than or equal to 270. This is based on a combined effort to improve the results of Zhang and Maynard.

Answer (score 2):

Answer in the comments by David Mitra:

> There are arbitrarily long sequences of successive integers, all of which are composite. (Start with n!+2.)

So no, the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html

The other comments are referring to the fact that arbitrarily large gaps can be found between consecutive prime numbers, therefore the difference you asked about does not have any upper bound. Check the link above for more information on the behavior of the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

$n!+2, n!+3, n!+4, ..., n!+n$, or using product of prime called a primoral $p_n$#$ = 2*3*5*...*p_n$ another smaller gap can be found of similar size.

$ p_n$#$ + 2, p_n$#$ + 3, p_n$#$ + 4, ..., p_n$#$ + p_n$.

Now all you have to do is let n go to infinity.